# Android Notification will not get displayed on device

Tags: android, notifications

I can not figure out why this notification will not get displayed on the device. The device I am using is running OS9. Any help would be great!

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d("TestApp", "Notification Received : " + remoteMessage.getData());


    NotificationUtils.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).createChannel(NotificationUtils.DEFAULT_CHANNEL);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = buildBasicNotification(getApplicationContext(), remoteMessage.getFrom(), remoteMessage.getData().get("_msg"), NotificationUtils.DEFAULT_CHANNEL);
    displayNotification(notification);

}

public static NotificationCompat.Builder buildBasicNotification(Context context, String title, String msgText, String channelId) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(msgText)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon)
            .setAutoCancel(false);

    return builder;
}


private void displayNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

Here are two important methods inside of the NotificationUtils

```
public static NotificationUtils getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new NotificationUtils(context);
    }

    return instance;
}

NotificationUtils(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        createAlertChannel();
        deleteChannel("Miscellaneous");
    }
}
```

Comment: Any error logs in `LogCat` ?

Comment: Nothing in the logcat, no. App doesnt crash, no try/catch so nothing to catch. i ran through debugger and the builder was building...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, finally.

The error was inside of this method.

```
public static NotificationCompat.Builder buildBasicNotification(Context context, String title, String msgText, String channelId) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(msgText)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon)
            .setAutoCancel(false);

    return builder;
}
```

Make sure that the `NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)` takes in the channelId.

So it should be... `NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)`